# Programmatically populating shapefile field with polygon areas in OGR?

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr, polygon-creation

I'm trying to programmatically populate a shp field with polygon areas:

```
import sys
import ogr

ds = ogr.Open( 'tttttttttt.shp', update = 1 )
if ds is None:
    print "Open failed./n"
    sys.exit( 1 )

lyr = ds.GetLayerByName( "tttttttttt" )
lyr.ResetReading()

field_defn = ogr.FieldDefn( "Area", ogr.OFTReal )
lyr.CreateField(field_defn)

for i in lyr:
    # feat = lyr.GetFeature(i) 
    geom = i.GetGeometryRef()
    area = geom.GetArea()
    print 'Area =', area
    lyr.SetFeature(i)
    i.SetField( "Area", area )

ds = None
```

But I get an empty values in the field...

Comment: Can you share a dummy shape file?

Comment: how do I share it? email?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b5uyzqf7oowsv8e/lL9bHRHTCT

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to  use `lyr.SetFeature(i)` to trigger the update in your shape file.
<strike>You'll have to close the data sources in the end so things get written.</strike>

```
import sys
import ogr

ds = ogr.Open( 'tttttttttt.shp', update = 1 )
if ds is None:
    print "Open failed./n"
    sys.exit( 1 )

lyr = ds.GetLayerByName( "tttttttttt" )
lyr.ResetReading()

field_defn = ogr.FieldDefn( "Area", ogr.OFTReal )
lyr.CreateField(field_defn)

for i in lyr:
    # feat = lyr.GetFeature(i) 
    geom = i.GetGeometryRef()
    area = geom.GetArea()
    print 'Area =', area
    lyr.SetFeature(i)
    i.SetField( "Area", area )
    lyr.SetFeature(i)
ds = None
```

*Low-rep comment and concern: If the 'Area' field already exists, this code creates an extra field, like "Area_n", and overwrites the existing Area field.  Maybe folks should add some safety code like:

```
ldef = lyr.GetLayerDefn()
if ldef.GetFieldIndex("Area") != -1:
    print "'Area' field already defined"
    ... # exit or overwrite logic
```

Comment: You're welcome. An upvote would be nice, too ;-)

Comment: I have similar project in .net,code is similar as well.In your code you mentioned that after SetField method,should use SetFeature in order to update layer.Unfortunately that doesn't work.Any ideas ?

Comment: @Myra You might want to ask that on a separate question. Unfortunately, I'm not really familiar with .NET. Hopefully, others can help you. Just post the question :)

Comment: Great, wonder why "SetFeature" is mentioned nowhere in the docs...